# Super Sticky Chrome Cache

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am in a testing nightmare. Chrome caches even on incognito mode. Is there any tool/plugin that I can use to effectively delete chrome cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have "Developer Options" open (like if you click Inspect Element), you can right-click the reload button for some options. One of these is the "clear cache and hard reload" option. This should do what you need.